# Stepped out onto the balcony

Tags: word-choice, colloquial-language

"Stepped out onto the balcony" is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stepped%20out%20onto%20the%20balcony%2Cstepped%20out%20into%20the%20balcony%2Cstepped%20out%20to%20the%20balcony&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstepped%20out%20onto%20the%20balcony%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstepped%20out%20into%20the%20balcony%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstepped%20out%20to%20the%20balcony%3B%2Cc0) than "stepped out to/into the balcony."

Why is "onto" used even though, usually, the floor of a balcony isn't higher than that of indoor rooms?

[image]

Comment: It's ***onto*** because the balcony is a ***surface*** - it's not a ***container***, since 3 of 4 sides (and often the "roof / lid" as well) aren't present. We use ***onto*** for surfaces, ***into*** for containers, and plain ***to*** for non-specific "destination" contexts, so *in principle* you could *step out **to** the balcony*. But ***onto*** is a better fit (because it's more "accurate"), so that's what's preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it this way:

The balcony prevents you from falling. Without it, you are walking off the building. Plus, it is an **extension** of the balcony, so you walk **onto** it is more commonly used, and walking **on/to** it is less commonly used.

Additionally, the balcony is sort of "separated" from the rest of the house, and hangs *away* from the house, so walking **onto** may seem more popularly used.

As what @FumbleFingers has said in the comments, it's onto because the balcony is a surface - it's not a container, since 3 of 4 sides (and often the "roof / lid" as well) aren't present. We use onto for surfaces, into for containers, and plain to for non-specific "destination" contexts, so in principle you could step out to the balcony. But onto is a better fit (because it's more "accurate"), so that's what's preferred.

Comment: This doesn't explain why we don't use _into_ (for which, see @FumbleFingers' comment above).